# Using customer display on Oracle Micros Workstation 310R with Linux

Tags: linux, display

I have a Oracle Micros Workstation 310R with Linux installed. The integrated customer display seems to be at /dev/ttyUSB2 but it doesn't seem to use the usual ESC/P command set. Where could I get information about how to use the customer display? Or is there any Windows software for using this customer display?

The LCD customer display goes black after a while when writing random data to /dev/ttyUSB2 and also tried normal ESC/P commands which do not work.